Trouble mounting directory into container in Github action
There's a documentation-building task I run in a Docker container on my Mac like so:
docker run --name build_docs_task \
   --mount type=bind,source=$HOME,target=/home/user/mounted_home \
   --workdir /home/user/mounted_home/my_code_repo/doc \
   -t --rm \
   escomp/base \
   make BUILDDIR=/home/user/mounted_home/my_docs_repo/versions/master -j 4 html

As I understand it, this mounts the doc directory into the escomp/base container and runs the doc-building task (that last line, with make) in there, telling make to put the outputs in doc/../../my_docs_repo/versions/master/. The results end up outside the container, presumably because that latter directory is mounted inside the container too.
I'm trying to build a Github action that will do this doc-building automatically for pull requests in my_code_repo. I don't actually care about the output per se; I just want to make sure there are no errors.
sphinx-action seems perfect for this. I've forked it and made a branch (latest commit permalink: 9571452) that uses the escomp/base container. I then created a branch in my code repo with a workflow, pr-docs-check.yml, to call that action.
In testing on my Mac (using act), this works! However, it fails on Github in the build step, complaining about the following line in my Dockerfile:
RUN --mount=type=bind,source=_build,target=/home/user/mounted_home/_build

Specifically:
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref 584d62f5-11d9-4074-87e4-acacf60905a6::lo2yv1zfyixtwqqcdheigo0u0: "/_build": not found

It seems to be looking for the build output directory (here, _build) at the top level of the Github runner, but it's obviously not there. I have a line in the Dockerfile that creates _build/ (a few lines up from the problematic one), but I'm not 100% what the full path of _build/ is.
What am I missing here? How do I get Docker to look in the right place for the build output directory?
I've searched around, and the most relevant advice seems to apply to how I can mount volumes in a container if the container is specified in the workflow .yml file. But (a) it's actually specified in my action's Dockerfile, and (b) I don't understand what the info at that link is trying to tell me anyway.
